# Get Visual Studio 2012/2013 to ignore multimedia keys

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, keyboard-shortcuts

Anyone know of a way to get Visual Studio to ignore multimedia key presses.

By these I mean Play, Pause, Next, Previous etc that come with most laptops and with almost all wireless keyboards. As of now, the only way to pause or skip a track that you may be listening to via a multimedia key is to click on the windows explorer task bar (or any other window), then press the key on the keyboard. If you press it when focused on visual studio, nothing happens. Visual Studio gobbles it up like the cookie monster!

Comment: Indeed it is a dup. The answer in that post solved it for me. Strange I couldn't find it when I searched the firs time. Though I was searching for "multimedia keys" not "media keys".